# How can a 4-bit CPU have 40 instructions?

Tags: cpu, ram, bus, register, instruction-set

Currently, I am using Logisim (yes, still Logisim) to build a 4-bit variant of the 8-bit SAP-1 microcomputer. However, I ran into a problem with the instruction register. Let me explain.

The SAP-1 has 5 instructions (LDA, ADD, SUB, OUT, HLT). These 5 instructions amount to 3 bits of data to read those RAM words. But that leaves only 1 bit for the address, and that means only 2 RAM addresses. To fix the problem, I tried to make the RAM words 6-bit instead (I don't know why I chose 6). But then I realized that having 6-bit RAM words would mean a 6-bit bus, and therefore a 6-bit CPU, which isn't good. Yet, 4-bit microprocessors carry on with upwards 40 instructions with kilobytes of memory. How do they do it, and how can I implement it into my 4-bit SAP-1?

Comment: just look at x86, 6502, z80, countless others...as answered variable instruction length, the term 4-bit or 8-bit or 32-bit doesnt necessarily have any limits on number of instructions, size of operations, address space, or other.  Using the n-bit terminology is in general bad and creates more confusion than it solves.

Comment: Hm? I looked at the 4-bit Intel 4004 instrustion set and it had instructions that were 1 byte or more. Wouldn't 8-bit RAM addresses make the 4004 an 8-bit microprocessor, since those addresses have to go through the bus?

Comment: Again try not to get hung up on terms like "8-bit", "16-bit" and so on, because they have fuzzy definitions at best and really dont mean anything.  They create more confusion than use.  whatever the vendor called is what you call it there is no definition, if you see a definition in some dictionary or wikipedia, then it is wrong because the term is based on opintion, some folks think the deifnition is register size, some, address bus size, some data bus size, alu size and so on.

Comment: since it is rare for a processor to have all of those things the same size then you will generally have a strong difference of opinion on the term.  x86 is an 8 bit instruction so do we call it an 8-bit processor?  how many people call it that (other than maybe me).  the 8088 was really a "16-bit" processor with an 8 bit external bus, but the thing was  designed as a "16" bit processor, so do we call it that?  it had a 20 bit address bus do we call it 20 bits, now it has 64 bit registers and a really wide data bus do we call it something else?

Comment: or just not bother with using terms that mean nothing useful and only cause problems.

Comment: think of it as a marketing term and not an engineering term.  which is really what it is, and the marketing department for the specific company that makes that product, gets to pick the term with or without any technical backup.  Does not have to conform to any other companies definition, instead used to make a product look better than the competitions with a bigger number.  And it should be used as a marketing term not an engineering term.  Like countless other terms folks get confused about thinking they have some technical meaning or definition.

Comment: better terms are 4 bit opcode with variable length instructions, can go into more detail if you choose (this being your thing YOU get to create the definition and you cant be wrong because it is your term/definition for your invention).  4 bit opcode, x bit registers y bit data bus z bit address bus, etc, etc. or if you choose you can simply call it a 4 bit processor and have 256 instructions with 32 bit registers, 64 bit data bus and 128 bit address bus and you wont be wrong because it is your invention and your definition.

Comment: The fact that these questions keep happening demonstrates the power of marketing and the value those departments have, they are not just money pits.  The term hooked you in caused you to research their product, ask questions about it, marketing success their product is embedded in your brain, good, bad, or otherwise. If they intentionally go off the rails then you spread the word like a joke to friends, etc who then research and get it in their brains, marketing success.  Look the new 256-bit risc-v processor from XYZ bench marked at 10 times the performance of an x86-64

Comment: have a look at this reference to Microchip's 8 bit microcontroller that uses 12 bit instruction set ... https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/han/Lambda/webdocs/PIC_Instruction_Reference-1.pdf

Comment: You can have 8-bit instructions where the CPU needs to process the first half and then the second half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The SAP-1 has 5 instructions(LDA, ADD, SUB, OUT, HLT). These 5 instructions amount to 3 bits of data to read those RAM words. But that leaves only 1 bit for the address, and that means only 2 RAM addresses.

I think there are some serious misconceptions here.  Being "4 bit" does **not** mean that your instructions are necessarily 4 bit, just as being 64 bit does not mean that your instructions are 64 bit.  If you want to build a 4 bit CPU, you should look at what your CPU needs to do, and then pick an instruction size that makes sense for the application.  Practical CPUs typically have either at least 16 bit instructions or a mechanism to make instructions variable length simply because a 4 bit instruction length doesn't let you do very much.

> Yet, 4-bit microprocessors carry on with upwards 40 instructions with kilobytes of memory. How do they do it, and how can I implement it into my 4-bit SAP-1?

First, lets pick a common definition of what "4 bit" means.  We'll say it means a system that has the general purpose integer registers all 4 bit.  It doesn't mean that all registers are only 4 bit, but we'll assume the basic ones are.  In that case, and with byte addressable memory, you would be limited to 16 bytes of RAM.

If you want more you have a few options:

1. Make the address space larger, in which case you will probably need to make the registers larger, in which case you arguably no longer have a 4 bit processor
2. Make the address space larger, but introduce a specific address register that is larger than the general purpose registers that can hold larger addresses (e.g. you have 4 bit integer registers and a special 16 bit register for memory pointers).  Note that this may require you to be able to do ALU operations on greater than 4 bit values.
3. Introduce a memory bank mechanism, where you have multiple 4 bit banks you can swap between, possibly by writing to a specific register, using a specific instruction, etc.  This effectively just encodes memory addresses in two (or more) register values.

Answer (score 2):

Variable-length instructions ---- suppose you want to jump with an offset of 550 from
the current program counter? Uses at least 3 of the 4-bit nibbles, just for the JumpOffset. Plus the opcode, which for Jump with Offset may need 2 more nibbles.

Comment: Well, Jump with Offset isn't part of the instruction set. Is there a way to simplify it for a different instruction, like ADD or LDA?

Answer (score 2):

Also with the address problem, it doesn't mean that a 4 bit CPU can only handle 4 bit addresses, as an 8 bit CPU (like a Commodore 64 in the good old days) can also address 64 KB of memory which is 16 bits.

It just means, it cannot handle it at once, so first 8 bits are loaded, and than another 8 bits.

So if your CPU needs to handle 1 GB, it is still possible with 4 bits, but you need many of those to acquire the final complete address within the 1 GB.

Comment: Alright, but this is the SAP-1, it is a very simplistic computer, is there a simpler way than fetching the memory twice?

Comment: If you need more bits than you can fetch in one go and you want to avoid multiple fetches.... try magic? (But first consider instruction prefixes, mode bits, multiple word instructions, different bit widths for code and data, etc.)

Comment: Alright, but variable machine cycles seem like they would require massive amounts of hardware to implement.

Comment: If you don't want variance, and it does not fit in a 4-bit 'word', than you need a multiple of them, say 2, which makes 256 possibilities, but yes, you need to fetch two times.

Comment: Maybe I could do bytes instead of nibbles for the RAM? It might work.

Comment: True, than you can fetch 8 bits at once

Comment: Then it's an 8-bit computer.

Comment: @user253751 Right

Answer (score 1):

All commands have a code and value. For example, imagine a command called ‘add to accumulator’. What do you add? You have to add a value along side, so a 4 bit system has 4 commands yet can have a much longer value, and each line of code can be many commands as well as many values

Comment: I would also note that some systems can have many cpus and therefore can have varying bits per command. For example(from what I have heard), the famous ti-84 calculator uses a sometimes-4bit-sometimes-24bit-system. I would go further to mention that you can in fact have a cpu with a #bit where the # is not a power of 2, as there are many 48 but computers out there in the world still in use, and I am currently working on ideas for a code that is 6 bits and can have a value of 12 bits for expanded memory. It is also important to know that the value can mean other things for different commands.

Comment: It is necessary to have the knowledge that many computers work many different ways. Some can have a value embedded within the command as some can have it separate. Some may have two different cpus with different codes that can yet interact with one another. Computer coding and design requires creativity and I would recommend making your own method and constantly improve it for the best results. Also note that one size does not fit all, meaning that every computer is unique and therefore the ‘skeleton’ or rather ‘backbone’ of a computer’s hardware is unique to its model, so keep crafting ideas!

Comment: Furthermore, I am speaking as an explorer of computers rather than a true coder, yet I am learning very fast. However, I still have much to learn, so as a new contributor as well as a rookie to the subject matter, I would highly request guidance and additional honest criticism so I may not spread possible misinformation and misguidance, as I wish to share useful and interesting solutions to problems rather than utter garbage of data, filling up one’s screen.

Comment: To tie it all together(in my method of solving the problem, as there are many solutions), the ‘codes’ or ‘commands’ would be called an opcode, and the value assigned would be called the operand(I think, if this is wrong please give me feedback), and every line in a basic computer(not basic the computer language, basic as in low-level coding) would be an opcode followed by an operand, where the operand can vary in bit length and can have a different purpose on different opcodes(usually).

Comment: Examples can include the mentioned LDA(which I assume means loading a memory value into the accumulator). Lets us say that the opcode for LDA is $0(0000 in binary) and we have 16 nibbles of memory(a nibble is 4 bits) and the accumulator is 1 nibble long. If we want to load memory slot $0 into the accumulator, we would say LDA 0, which goes to slot $0 in the memory and puts it as the new value into the accumulator, with LDA being the code and 0 being the value

Answer (score 1):

The width of the instructions, registers, external data bus width, internal logical units busses, can be all different.

For example, the HP Saturn processor, which was used in calculators, is usually considered "4bits" :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Saturn

- 4bits addressing granularity
- 8bits external bus
- 64bits registers
- 4bits internal architecture
- Instructions are variable length, multiple of 4bits

Comment: Some computers have the data bus and the instructions bus totally separate.  I remember a computer with 8 bit data and 12 bit instructions.